# How do I upload an .ino file into a Arduino Uno from a headless ( No X11 ) Raspberry Pi?

Tags: linux

**FYI (AKA before people start down voting)**

[image]

I have a simple sketch called `test.ino`. I can run it from my macbook without issue. However, when I try to hook the Arduino Uno directly up to the raspberry pi (2) I see the port that is being used is `ttyACM0` but when I run `sudo arduino --upload test.ino --port /dev/ttyACM0`, I get...

> Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException: 
>   No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.

How do I avoid this?

**Update**

```
***@robotbrain:~/Code/rpi/green$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2341:0001 Arduino SA Uno (CDC ACM)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMC9514 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

You can confirm no x11 by...

```
...@robotbrain:~$ xdpyinfo | grep version
xdpyinfo:  unable to open display "".
```

Comment: You will have to run the command line Arduino utility. Ask on the Arduino site

Comment: @Milliways I did they transferred it here problems with SO :-(

Comment: you do not upload `ino` files ... you upload compiled `hex` files ... use `avrdude` for that

Comment: Awesome @jsotola give me the way to compile an `ino` file to `hex` so I can use `avrdude` and you get the nod ;-)

Comment: Rt but per the post the arduino cli still requires X11

Comment: arduino-cli does not work in a terminal?

Comment: Not if we are talking about the same thing and you do not have X11 (desktop)

Comment: i think that your question is actually about how to use linux ... anyway, here is a video about arduino-cli ... you only need a terminal window, no X11 required ... https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=0GksD2cCDTs

Comment: @jsotola Not sure what you mean that machine he is running on in the video is def using x11

Comment: that is just a terminal console window ... same as if you SSH into the RPi ... if you do not start X11, then you will be at a login prompt ... that is the same thing as the X11 window in the youtube video

Comment: @Jackie The question is not specific to the Pi - the compiler is a java program, and could run on any computer with java. It should NOT have been transferred here. AFAIK there is no need for X11 - you just need java.

Answer (score 1):

For compiling Arduino code on the command line, I usually use
[Sudar Muthu's Makefile](https://github.com/sudar/Arduino-Makefile). It
is available on Raspbian as the `arduino-mk` package:

```sh
sudo apt install arduino-mk
mkdir arduino-test
cd arduino-test
cat > arduino-test.ino <<EOF
void setup() {
    pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}
void loop() {
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, !digitalRead(LED_BUILTIN));
    delay(200);
}
EOF
cat > Makefile <<EOF
BOARD_TAG = uno
include /usr/share/arduino/Arduino.mk
EOF
make
make upload
```

The only problem is that you end up using the Arduino core version
1.0.5, which is quite ancient. You can set up the per-project Makefile
for using a more recent core, but this requires some configuration. Here
is a Makefile I use on Ubuntu with a 1.8.10 core unpacked in /opt:

```makefile
ARDMK_DIR     = /usr/share/arduino
ARDUINO_DIR   = /opt/arduino-1.8.10
AVRDUDE_CONF  = /etc/avrdude.conf
USER_LIB_PATH = $(realpath ../..)
ARDUINO_LIBS  = Wire RTClib
ARDUINO_QUIET = 1
BOARD_TAG     = uno

include $(ARDMK_DIR)/Arduino.mk
```

I didn't check it works on Raspbian though.

Answer (score 0):

**Raspberry Pi 2 and Arduino Uno**

*I am not going to accept this as the answer because I want to compile the ino on the pi!*

I could do this...

1. Compile the ino file to a hex file on an os with an IDE (my case my macbook pro)
2. SCP the .hex file up to the raspberry pi (assuming test.hex)
3. SSH into the raspberry pi
4. Run the following... `sudo avrdude -p m328p -carduino -e -U flash:w:test.hex -P/dev/ttyACM0`

Comment: Why would you want to go through this complex process when you could just run Arduino on the Mac (or indeed any other computer) or even use the on-line version.

Comment: Because I want to automate it and not have to control the flow of my artifact. Why would we ask why and not figure that things can be contained without outside influence?